# Change BIOS Settings Without Video Card

Tags: video, bios

My video card broke now a while ago and I have been using my computer by connecting to it via the network. Now I need to change the BIOS settings on it. Can I do that without a working video card? I have monitors.

Comment: What motherboard is this?

Comment: If your graphic card is not working, what use do monitors do you, you don't have way to display the BIOS screen.  I suggest just replacing the GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot change BIOS settings without a functional video adapter. However you can try following:

1. Check if your motherboard has on board video output.
2. For access to BIOS, you can use the cheapest video adapter you can find that fits in the slot on motherboard. You donot need a powerful 3D accelerated video adapter for gaming.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check my motherboard for #1, and if that doesn't work out, I'll take a video card from another unused machine and use it change the BIOS on this one.

Answer (score 3):

In some server and other "very serious" motherboards you can access BIOS via terminal connected to COM port, but I guess most of consumer motherboards have no such feature.

There is also Intel System Management, but I think this is available for servers. It is designed to manage computers remotely and you can change BIOS options with this.

[image]

Image source:
http://www.intel.com/

Comment: Thanks Kamil for the suggestion, but I think I just have consumer-type motherboard...

Comment: Just to add some information, "very serious motherboards" also includes things like servers with remote access cards (e.g. HP ILO, Dell RAC, ...).